# Can Javascript Promises be created with a single parameter?

Tags: javascript, promise

When we create a `Promise()`, the constructor expects two parameters: `resolve` and `reject`.
Can I create a Promise using only **resolve**?

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {});
```

I've tried and it works. But, it is a good practice? The promise is expected to be resolved in all circumstances.

Comment: `When we create a Promise(), the constructor expects two parameters: resolve and reject.` No, it doesn't. The constructor expects _one_ parameter, a function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's doable. If

- you're sure the Promise will always resolve, or
- there is no real way to detect if an error occurs (in which case a `reject` parameter wouldn't be used anyway)

then using only the `resolve` parameter is a reasonable possibility.

If there's any chance of an error - even an unexpected error - it'd be a good idea to use the `reject` parameter, though. Many errors are not expected, after all.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can with

```
Promise.resolve(value);
```

refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve